Formally etale and etale
Let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes over an algebraically closed field $k$ which is formally etale and an injection on $k$-points. Is $f$ etale? If not, what are some additional properties that will guarantee it is etale?

Etale is equivalent to formally etale + locally of finite presentation (ref), so you need to show that your setup implies locally of finite presentation. How far do you get with that?

I was basically wondering if havening an injection on k-points (or having a finite number of k-points in the fiber) is enough to ensure finite presentation for formally etale maps... My intuition is that fibers of a formally etale map can fail to be etale only by having fibers which are infinite disjoint union of points, but I have no idea if that's correct
